# netbios domain rename

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

we have windows server 2008 r2 domain controllers. the forest and domain functional level is windows server 2003 (it's possible to raise the levels). we have an exchange 2010 server.

i would like to rename the netbios domain name (pre-windows 2000 domain name). i don't touch the dns domain name.

so if i just rename the netbios domain name is there any impact to the exchange organisation?

a best practice for renaming the netbios domain name would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen this request numerous times in numerous forums.  Rather than reinvent the wheel, I want to point you to a blog article written by Ace Fekay that does an excellent job explaining how to perform this task.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2009/08/19/domain-rename-with-or-without-exchange.aspx

Comment: The linked blog no longer contains portions of the process.  Effectively the same steps are in TechNet (the blog likely plagiarized them): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794869(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a full domain rename (which you can't do since you are running Exchange) or a domain migration to a different domain (which will require a new FQDN domain name)